# Swift Add array values into a multi- dimensional array

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to add an array to a multi-dimensional array so i can add values to the existing array created.. I'm having trouble with this in swift so some help would be awesome

```
var array = [String]()
var NewArraywithValues = [[array],[int],[int]]
```

also how do i append the second and third values depending on the array `String`

Thanks

Comment: Your code is not legal Swift, so it's impossible to deduce your intentions from it. What exactly are you wishing to do? How many "dimensions" did you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to do. But you can make an array with other arrays as sub-arrays: But you can do something like that:

```
var stringArray = [String]()
var intArray = [Int]()
var doubleArray = [Double]()
var NewArraywithValues = [stringArray,intArray,doubleArray]
```

Also you could make an array-array of Objects:

```
var arrayArray:[[YourDataType]]
```

You then access the objects with:

```
var item = arrayArray[1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of strings: `[String]`

An array of arrays of strings: `[[String]]`

The first element of the first array in an array of arrays of strings: `arr[0][0]`